# Using enum as key for map

Tags: java, enums

I want to use `enum` as keys and a object as value. Here is the sample code snippet:

```
public class DistributorAuditSection implements Comparable<DistributorAuditSection>{      

     private Map questionComponentsMap;  

     public Map getQuestionComponentsMap(){  
         return questionComponentsMap;  
     }  

     public void setQuestionComponentsMap(Integer key, Object questionComponents){  
         if((questionComponentsMap == null)  || (questionComponentsMap != null && questionComponentsMap.isEmpty())){ 
             this.questionComponentsMap = new HashMap<Integer,Object>();  
         }  
         this.questionComponentsMap.put(key,questionComponents);  
     }
}
```

It is now a normal hashmap with integer keys and and object as values. Now I want to change it to `Enummap`. So that I can use the `enum` keys. I also don't know how to retrieve the value using `Enummap`.

Comment: What have you tried? What happens when you use `EnumMap`? To get help you need to be more specific and show you've done your homework.

Answer (score 53):

It the same principle as `Map` Just Declare `enum` and use it as `Key` to `EnumMap`.

```
public enum Color {
    RED, YELLOW, GREEN
}

Map<Color, String> enumMap = new EnumMap<Color, String>(Color.class);
enumMap.put(Color.RED, "red");
String value = enumMap.get(Color.RED);
```

You can find more about `Enums` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Thx.  I was missing the Colors.RED concept for declaring a constant: i.e.
private static final Colors R  = Colors.RED;

Comment: why we have added Color.class in map argument ??

Answer (score 9):

Just replace `new HashMap<Integer, Object>()` with `new EnumMap<MyEnum, Object>(MyEnum.class)`.

Comment: public void setQuestionComponentsMap(Integer key, Object questionComponents){  what can i pass in the place of "Integer key"?coz now i am retrving enum keys.

Comment: If you can change the signature of that method then just replace the Integer argument with your Enum type...