# Accessing static variables using an enum

Tags: java, enums

There exists a class that defines a set of constants as such

```
public class CritterCode {

    public static String KITTY = "KT";
    public static String PUPPY = "PP";
}
```

I have created an enum that will be used in a combo box.

```
public enum Critter {
   KITTY,
   PUPPY
}
```

Given a `Critter`, I would like to obtain the corresponding `CritterCode`.

Is it possible to accomplish this without writing duplicate code?

Comment: Use an EnumMap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669569/2591612

Comment: Make a string field in the enum and a constructor and make something like that KITTY("KT), PUPPY("PP")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public enum Critter {
    KITTY(CritterCode.KITTY),
    PUPPY(CritterCode.PUPPY)

    private final String code;

    private Critter(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Do it like this,

```
public enum Critter {
  KITTY("KT"),
  PUPPY("PP");

  private String code;
  Critter(String code) {
      this.code = code;
  }

  public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
  }
}
```

this way you can get rid of `CritterCode`.

Comment: You should use the `static` variables as @JBNizet has done - I don't think this answer qualifies under the _without writing duplicate code_ criteria.

Comment: there's no duplicate code, this way it's pointless to use `CritterCode`.

Comment: Assume that `CritterCode` cannot be modified and is used elsewhere. If one of `String` values there is changed for whatever reason this change would need to be copied to `Critter`.

Comment: @CamiloBermúdez There is duplicate code. CritterCode already contains the strings "KT" and "PP" as stated in the question.  This answer states nothing about removing the existing CritterCode class

Comment: @Boris he doesn't explicitly state that `CritterCode` is irreplaceable, so it was obvious to me that he was using it because he didn't know it could be done this way, anyway, let's wait to see what the OP has to say

Comment: @bdrx thought it was obvious, but yes, you're right, just edited, thanks.

Comment: +1. Actually there are two cases: one that I am designing myself anew, and another that is already in use which is irreplaceable. I didn't know enums could have methods so that makes it much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

use enum properties

```
public enum Critter {
   KITTY("KT"),
   PUPPY("PP");

    String critterCode;

    public Critter(String critterCode) {
        this.critterCode = critterCode;
    }

    public String getCritterCode() {
        this.critterCode;
    }
}
```